# What is the distribution of the firetrucks in stationarity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was doing an old exam and came across the following question: The 112 emergency operators in the Eindhoven region dispatch ambulances and firetrucks according to independent Poisson processes with intensities $\lambda_a$ and $\lambda_f$ per hour, respectively.

It takes a firetruck a uniformly distributed amount of time with a mean of $\beta$ hours to return to its base after it has been dispatched. What is the distribution of the number of firetrucks out on the road (i.e., away from their base) in stationarity?

I have no clue how to answer this question. So any help would be great, thanks